# What were the manpower and gunnery levels of the seven gunboats that assisted Grant at Fort Donelson?

Tags: military, american-civil-war

Earlier on, I asked a question about General Grant's "true" force level at [Fort Donelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Fort_Donelson). The argument was that Grant had been assisted by gunboats and gunners that were technically not under his command, but effectively raised his force levels.

Although the original (convoluted) question was closed and deleted, here is a simpler, more objective version focused on the relevant facts:

What were the number and caliber of the gunboat cannon that assisted Grant at Fort Donelson? How many men manned the ships and guns? (I believe I have a handle on the relevant land-based factors but not the naval ones.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [a description of the Cairo](https://weaponsandwarfare.com/2018/10/21/union-ironclads-of-the-mississippi-river/), typical of all the *city class* ironclad gunboats in Foote's' flotilla.

> [image]

As noted the crew establishment of each was 251 officers and men, with a gun battery comprised of:

- 3 x 8" smoothbore, numbered (9) below: 1 mounted as bow chaser and 1 on each broadside;
- 3 x 42 lb rifled cannon, numbered (10) below: 2 mounted as bow chasers, and 1 on starboard;
- 6 x 32 lb rifled cannon, numbered (11) below, 3 on each broadside;
- 1 x 30 lb rifled cannon, numbered (12) below; and
- 1 * 12 lb rifled cannon.

Comment: I had earlier thought that Grant's success at Fort Donelson was due largely to the gunboats, but after reading your two excellent answers, it seems that other factors (the fort's inherent vulnerability) may have been more important.